# Sign a text with pynacl (Ed25519) importing a private key

Tags: python, python-3.x, ed25519, nacl-cryptography, pynacl

In the code below I try to sign a nonce using pynacl.

```
from nacl.encoding import Base64Encoder
from nacl.signing import SigningKey
import base58
import base64

secret = '5N3SxG4UzVDpNe4LyDoZyb6bSgE9tk3pE2XP5znXo5bF'
nonce = '3eaf8814caa842d94fdb96fc26d02f7c339e65ff'

h=hashlib.new('sha256')
h.update(str.encode(nonce))
hashednonce = h.hexdigest()

key = base58.b58decode(secret)
signingkey = SigningKey(key)

signednonce = signingkey.sign(hashednonce.encode())
```

That secret key is in base58 (Don't worry, it's not mine and is publicly posted [here](https://wiki.iota.org/integration-services/basics/authentication/example_node)). In that page is also the signature it should output, but it's not the same.

I'm afraid that the key is being imported in the wrong way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sign()` method of the used NodeJS library expects key and message hex encoded, see [here](https://github.com/paulmillr/noble-ed25519/blob/main/index.ts#L926). The hex format is rather a special characteristic of this particular library.

In contrast, PyNaCl expects both as bytes like objects, see [here](https://pynacl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/signing/#example). For the key this is already satisfied, because `b58decode()` returns the data as bytes like object. For hashing the nonce it is easiest to use `digest()` instead of `hexdigest()`, then the hashed nonce is also returned as a bytes like object.

The result returned in the Python code from `sign()` consists of the concatenation of the 64 bytes signature and the hashed nonce, i.e. the first 64 bytes correspond to the signature from the NodeJS example.

Full code:

```py
from nacl.signing import SigningKey
import base58
import hashlib

secret = '5N3SxG4UzVDpNe4LyDoZyb6bSgE9tk3pE2XP5znXo5bF'
nonce = '3eaf8814caa842d94fdb96fc26d02f7c339e65ff'

h = hashlib.new('sha256')
h.update(nonce.encode('utf-8'))
hashednonce = h.digest()

key = base58.b58decode(secret)
signingkey = SigningKey(key)
signednonce = signingkey.sign(hashednonce)
print("Hashed nonce, hex:             " + hashednonce.hex())
print("Signature | hashed nonce, hex: " + signednonce.hex())
print("Signature, hex:                " + signednonce[:64].hex())
```

Output:

```
Hashed nonce, hex:             6d748f209e5af1f5b8825f7822d6659c45c874076cd2b3337c7861fd94cd3ba5
Signature | hashed nonce, hex: 270c2e502c5c753e39159683981e452444f81a10d798f56406a9c471d672a5ede1792cb7f97d4f9c9efeec7bf35577dd1f8482afca7e3710291868a65bf91e076d748f209e5af1f5b8825f7822d6659c45c874076cd2b3337c7861fd94cd3ba5
Signature, hex:                270c2e502c5c753e39159683981e452444f81a10d798f56406a9c471d672a5ede1792cb7f97d4f9c9efeec7bf35577dd1f8482afca7e3710291868a65bf91e07
```

As can be seen, the hashed nonce and the signature correspond to the values from the NodeJS example.

Comment: Btw the hashing can be done in one line as `hashlib.sha256(nonce).digest()`

Comment: You are a hero! Now it works perfecly.